# Angular Reactive form rendering issue breaking the form

Tags: javascript, angular

So I am having a very weird problem with Angular reactive form. I asked my instructor, he couldn't figure it out so I have only one place I am wishing to get some help from. It's here.
So I am using a Angular form and the signup.component.html code snippet is:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="onSaveUser()" *ngIf="!isLoading">

  <mat-accordion class="accordion-headers-align">
    <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="1">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>Personal data</mat-panel-title>
        <mat-panel-description>Type your personal details</mat-panel-description>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>

      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="Name">
        <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('name').invalid">Please enter your name</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput type="date" formControlName="dob" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
        <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('dob').invalid">Please enter your valid date of birth in form of DD/MM/YYYY</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
```

and continue like that, ignore the accordion part pls.
Then my signup.component.ts file is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

  isLoading = false;
  form: FormGroup;
  imagePreview: string;

  constructor(public userService: UsersService, public route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(null, {validators: [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(3),
        // tslint:disable-next-line:quotemark
        Validators.pattern(some regex not of concern)
      ]}),
      dob: new FormControl(null, {validators: [
        Validators.required,
        // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length quotemark
        Validators.pattern(some regex not of concern)
      ]}),
```

and continued like this, nothing special. Just trying to map the form fields. So the form renders like this: The error I am getting in console is:

```
ERROR TypeError: "this.form is undefined, can't access property "get" of it".

ERROR Error: "formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

ERROR TypeError: "_co.form is undefined, can't access property "get" of it".
```

and I don't understand what is going wrong, I checked the documentation and everything, no help. I am guessing it's a possible bug so wanted to make sure.

Comment: Stackblitz please.

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera I have made that project locally, I can't upload the whole project.

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mtapsn here you go

Comment: Hi @MihirKumar Your stackblitz does not work, It is a not a platform just to show your code. Please provide verifiable example reproducing your issue.

Comment: @AmitChigadani for that I'll have to recreate a whole project of several components.

Comment: You need not to, You can still provide a minimal and verifiable example. I see that you are missing the packages and imports for the same. I would suggest you to fix them. So that you get better solutions to your problem.

Comment: @AmitChigadani I am doing it now. Pls check.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve with *ngIf="form", in this way form tag will be rendered only when form is ready.

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="onSaveUser()" *ngIf="form">
```

Comment: But this should also work as I am using mat-spinner to load it while the form isn't loaded.

Comment: Fix me if I'm wrong, you want to see "mat-spinner" till form is ready, right?
And "isLoading" should hide "mat-spinner" and show "form" ? 

If ok, *ngIf="form && !isLoading"

Comment: Yeah, that's possible but see the error, it's in the get part and some other stuff. My spinner is loading fine, but my form is rendering weird.

Comment: Try with "?" to avoid check null properties 

*ngIf="form?.get('name').invalid"